# Wifi proprietary driver issue

Tags: wireless, drivers, intel-wireless

I tried a 10.10 Live CD and a pop-up directed me to install a proprietary driver for my wifi card before I could browse. However, my only means for internet access is through my school's wireless access point. What do I do now, since I can't install the driver for the card, and the same card doesn't allow me to connect to the wireless network?  This is an Intel wireless card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know which package you need (probably firmware-iwlwifi) you can download and install it seperately.

You mention the use of the live cd, so what exactly are you after?

Comment: Trying my hands on ubuntu before the 11.04 is released. I'm a new windows migrant

Comment: I wouldn't bother too much with getting it installed in some live environment (unless you run from a usb stick and you can permanently install extra packages).  If you are preparing for a linux intstall and want to check for device drivers, open a terminal from your live session, and run the command `lspci -n`, then past the output lines on this site http://kmuto.jp/debian/hcl/ , it will verify your pci devices so you have an idea if your hardware is supported.